# ngCordova $cordovaFileTransfer - how to abort a download? abort() is undefined

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

Does anyone know how to abort a download while using the $cordovaFileTransfer plugin with ionic?

I have a view where the user has the option to download a file, but I want to make sure that if they start downloading the file, but then press the "back" button, it cancels the download and basically resets the view. What seems to be happening is when the download starts and the view is left, the download still does its thing, even though I'm trying to do something like this in the code:

```
// If the user leaves, check if a download is in progress.
    // - If so, reset the variable, and remove the directory
    $scope.$on('$ionicView.leave', function() {
      if($scope.downloading === true) {
        $scope.downloading = false;

        $cordovaFile.removeRecursively(cordova.file.dataDirectory, courseDir)
        .then(function (success) {
        });
      }
    });
```

I've tried calling $cordovaFileTransfer.abort() and it tells me there is no such function, even though I see an abort function in the plugin, itself. Does anyone have any insight into this, because I feel this would be a common piece of functionality that people are looking for.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem by going into the ng-cordova.js file directly and adding the abort function like so:

I made a global variable called ft inside of the factory object and removed the variable instantiation inside the "download" function, in order to make it global to all functions.

```
/* globals FileTransfer: true */
angular.module('ngCordova.plugins.fileTransfer', [])

  .factory('$cordovaFileTransfer', ['$q', '$timeout', function ($q, $timeout) {
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    return {
      download: function (source, filePath, options, trustAllHosts) {
        var q = $q.defer();
        var uri = (options && options.encodeURI === false) ? source : encodeURI(source);

        if (options && options.timeout !== undefined && options.timeout !== null) {
          $timeout(function () {
            ft.abort();
          }, options.timeout);
          options.timeout = null;
        }

        ft.onprogress = function (progress) {
          q.notify(progress);
        };

        q.promise.abort = function () {
          ft.abort();
        };

        ft.download(uri, filePath, q.resolve, q.reject, trustAllHosts, options);
        return q.promise;
      },

      upload: function (server, filePath, options, trustAllHosts) {
        var q = $q.defer();

        var uri = (options && options.encodeURI === false) ? server : encodeURI(server);

        if (options && options.timeout !== undefined && options.timeout !== null) {
          $timeout(function () {
            ft.abort();
          }, options.timeout);
          options.timeout = null;
        }

        ft.onprogress = function (progress) {
          q.notify(progress);
        };

        q.promise.abort = function () {
          ft.abort();
        };

        ft.upload(filePath, uri, q.resolve, q.reject, options, trustAllHosts);
        return q.promise;
      },

      /* Here is the added abort function that will
       kill the download or upload by calling $cordovaFileTransfer.abort() */
      abort: function() {
        var q = $q.defer;
        ft.abort();
        q.resolve;
        return q.promise;
      }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: What happens if there are multiple downloads?

Answer (score 0):

Abort is added to newer versions of download method of $cordovaFileTransfer, so a code like the following works with no problem if you upgrade your ngcordova:

```
var transferPromise = $cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, {}, true);
transferPromise.then(
    function () {  },                
    function () {  },
    function (progress) {   }
    );
.
.
.
transferPromise.abort();
```

Comment: This no longer seems to be a method in the NGCordova file - https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/blob/master/src/plugins/fileTransfer.js

Comment: Hi, it's there. download(...) returns a promise and abort() is added to that promise. check line 25.

Comment: I cannot get this to work - doing - 

$cordovaFileTransfer.fileDownloading = $cordovaFileTransfer.download( fullPath, path, options, trustHosts )
                    .then( ( function( result ) { }), ( function( error ) { }), function( progress ) {}, false );

And then later calling $cordovaFileTransfer.fileDownloading.abort() says no function - maybe i am processing the promise - and returning this ...

Comment: I edited the answer for you. please notice you should first get the promise then call, then() method of it.